# The best way to detect Oracle connection leak?

Tags: c#, oracle, resource-leak

A program written in C# Oracle client that proved to have "Connection leak" which it is not closing all database connections and so after some time it can no longer connect to the database as there are too many open connections.

I wrote the following helper function (quite expansive):

```
        private static int tryFindConnCount(){
            var connstk = new Stack<Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection>();
            try
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
                {
                    var conn = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(
                        myDatabaseConnection);
                    conn.Open();
                    connstk.Push(conn);
                }                
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                foreach (var conn in connstk)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
            return connstk.Count;
        }
```

Here is the code in a test case that uses the above:

```
            var co = tryFindConnCount();
            CodeThatMayLeakConnection();
            var cn = tryFindConnCount();

            Assert.That(cn, Is.EqaulTo(co));
```

It helped me identify at least one case that have connection leak.

The problem of `tryFindConnCount` is that it should never be used in production. And I think there should be some way to obtain the same value much cheaper.

How can I do this in the code so I can monitor this value in production?

Comment: You can query the Oracle db to get the total connection count of connections originating from that program. For example : select count(*)
from gv$session
where machine = 'XXXXX'
and username = 'YYYYY'
and program = 'ZZZZZ';

Comment: You only need some specific values that uniquely identify those connections like for example machine from which it originates --> "server.123.local.com", DB username with which the connections enter the database and maybe the program name like "clientprogram1" or some other attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to find places where connections where not closed is a difficult task.

If you leave the program and forget to close the connection the last sql which was executed is stored in column SQL_ID in v$session (gv$session for RAC). You can search v$session for idle/dead sessions. You can then use v$sql to find the SQL text which may tell you more about what was done last. By this you may get a hint where to search in your code.

```
select a.sid, a.username, a.program, a.machine, a.sql_id, b.sql_fulltext
  from v$session a, v$sql b
 where b.sql_id(+) = a.sql_id
   and a.username is not null  -- filter system processes, maybe filter more stuff
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query Oracle DB on "gv$session" view to get the info that you need. With a query on this view you can cyclically monitor the DB every 10-15 minutes for a count of connections from this program.

Example query below :

```
select count(*)
from gv$session
where machine = 'XXXXX'
and username = 'YYYYY'
and program = 'ZZZZZ';
```

You only need values that uniquely identify those connections like for example machine from which the connections originate.

Also the query is very light and doesn't add performance overhead.